# INSERT or UPDATE Table with Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to insert, update or delete data effectively from tables with foreign key constraints.

These are my sample tables:

```
CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_register (
  athlete_id    CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
  round_number  INT NOT NULL,
  discipline_id INT NOT NULL,
  register_date  DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  register_position INT DEFAULT NULL,
  register_time     TIME DEFAULT NULL,
  register_measure  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_register PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id, round_number, discipline_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_register_athlete FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_register_round FOREIGN KEY (discipline_id, round_number) REFERENCES olympic.tb_round (discipline_id, round_number)
);

CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_athlete    (
  athlete_id    CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
  name          CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
  country       CHARACTER VARYING(3) NOT NULL,
  substitute_id  CHARACTER(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_athlete PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_athlete_substitute FOREIGN KEY (substitute_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id)
);
```

When I run the command:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO tb_register  VALUES(7777777,7,7,'2022-06-02 00:00:00',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO  tb_athlete  VALUES(7777777,'xxxxxx','XXX','xxxxxxx');
DELETE FROM tb_register WHERE athlete_id = 1320573;
DELETE FROM tb_athlete WHERE athlete_id = 1320573;
COMMIT;
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "tb_register" violates foreign key constraint "fk_register_athlete"
DETAIL:  Key (athlete_id)=(7777777) is not present in table "tb_athlete".
SQL state: 23503
```

Can anyone help me understand how to solve this?

Thank you (:

Comment: Why use `character` if you want to store numbers? If the `athlete_id`  isn't really a number, then use at least `varchar(7)` - [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: You need to insert into the `tb_athlete` table first, then into `tb_register` after that.

Comment: The order of deletion is correct, but you can also use [`on delete cascade` and `on update cascade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html#:~:text=In%20addition%2C%20when,for%20each%20clause%3A) in your reference constraint so that you only need to issue a delete/update from `tb_athlete`, which will automatically delete/update the corresponding record in `tb_register`. The order of your `create table` statements should be reversed as well, for the same reason as your `insert`s - I assume they are here just for reference, otherwise the first one would fail.

Comment: Thank you @Zegarek issue solved! (:

Comment: @KlauRau I'm glad it worked. I made my coments into a proper [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70246316/5298879).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your `create table` and `insert` statements needs to be reversed. When `olympic.tb_register` comes to life it needs to already see `olympic.tb_athlete` for its reference constraints against that table to make sense - you can't force a table to make sure its rows match a not-yet-existing table.

It's the same situation for `insert`s: when a new row enters `olympic.tb_register`, it has to already see its corresponding row in `olympic.tb_athlete`. Otherwise it'll think someone is trying to register a non-existing athlete.

You can also use [`on delete cascade` and `on update cascade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html#:%7E:text=In%20addition%2C%20when,for%20each%20clause%3A) in your reference constraint so that you only need to issue a delete/update on `tb_athlete`, which will automatically delete/update the corresponding record in `tb_register`:

```sql
  CONSTRAINT fk_register_athlete 
     FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id) 
     REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```